# Utilizar atributos da classe filha

Tags: java, herança

Tenho um objeto da classe Conta "Conta contaSelecionada" porém, utilizando polimorfismo classes filhas são atribuídas a contaSelecionada.

```
public AlterarLimites(Conta conta) {
    contaSelecionada = conta;
    type = 1;
    initComponents();
}

public AlterarLimites(Poupanca conta) {
    contaSelecionada = conta;
    type = 2;
    initComponents();
}

public AlterarLimites(Salario conta) {
    contaSelecionada = conta;
    type = 3;
    initComponents();
}
```

contudo não consigo acessar métodos exclusivos das classes filhas de Conta dessa forma. o que poderia fazer para acessa-los?

Comment: está faltando código e um objeto declarado como `Conta` você quer acessar algo exclusivo de `ContaSelecionada`, é isso ?

Comment: Basicamente é o que está explicado na duplicata, é um problema de covariancia, ou seja, você não pode tratar um supertipo com um subtipo.